# Detecting whether any thread is waiting for an event

Tags: winapi

Let's say I have a manual event handle `h` (created with `CreateEvent`, manual).

There are several threads in my application, some thread(s) might be waiting for this event (`WaitForSingleObject`, `WaitForMultipleObject`).

At certain times in my application, I want to assert that no thread is waiting for this handle `h`.

Is there a Windows API function that tells me if any thread waiting for event `h` at that moment in time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the Windows API provides any public mechanism for giving out that information (whether or not threads are waiting for a synchronization object).  It is something that a typical application should not need to know and would likely result in race conditions if it were provided.

For example, if the application checked to verify that no threads were waiting and then made a decision based on that, it could easily be wrong because a thread may in the very next clock cycle actually start waiting for the event, so the information would be stale and potentially wrong immediately after the check.